# Как правильно строить диаграммы последовательности UML?

Tags: uml

Есть некий вариант использования приложения пользователем. В приложение 3 компонента: поле ввода и 2 кнопки. Пользователь вводит текст, затем жмет клавишу подтверждения, а затем клавишу выхода.

Правильно ли я для данного случая смог сделать диаграмму последовательности или есть ошибки?

Пример интерфейса:

[image]

Пример диаграммы:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я помню, диаграмму последовательности лучше применять для раскрытия последовательности функционирования однотипных объектов, например, объектов классов.

В Вашем случае напрашивается использовать диаграмму действий (Activity Diagram). Так как есть внешняя среда - **актер** и внутренняя - система (кнопки, поле). Также в Вашем примере пропадает или очень невелик смысл типов стрелочек (вызовов).

Но в целом, в качестве простого примера, сделано правильно.
Вернитесь к определению? для чего используется диаграмма последовательности.

**Что касается замечаний:**

Неясно, почему Вы ждете ответа от текстового поля после ввода текста?
Из практики: нижние объекты (прямоугольники) можно не указывать. Они уже есть вверху.